# Converting Yes to 1 and No to 0 in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file few columns are as Yes/No's I have tried most of the solutions on stack over flow nothing seems to be working.

```
sample['colval'] = sample['colval'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='N' else 1)
```

For example, I used the above code on my data. It converted everything to `1`'s, as in `Y` to `1` and `N` to `1`.

So many other examples too, all yielded similar results, few resulting in 'None' as output for Y/N.
`sample.colval[0:20]`

`0     N

1     N
2     N

3     N

4     N

5     N

6     N

7     N

8     N

9     N

10    N

11    Y

12    N

13    N

14    N

15    N

16    N

17    N

18    Y

19    N

Name: colval, dtype: object`

Please help, Thank you

Comment: just use some software such as libre calc or excel or whatever and replace all in selection... no reason to overthink

Comment: Do you have the case matching, you could do `0 if x.lower() == 'no' else 1`? If you can have both `no` and `n` then you can use `in` instead of `==`.

Comment: You should show an example of the data it's being used on (is it Yes/No, yes/no, or Y/N? you use them interchangeably in the question, but it matters, as `==` will only be true for exact matches)

Comment: `'N' == 'no'` is false, so it will be converted to 1. If you want to match `N`, you have to compare it to `'N'`. If you want to match anything starting with lowercase or uppercase `N`, you can write that—e.g., `if x.lower().startswith('n')`. But whatever you want to do, you have to write _that_; Python can't guess what you actually meant to write.

Comment: @janusvm It's Y/N , not yes/no or y/n.

Comment: @Vivia in that case, you need to check for `x == 'N'`, since 'N' and 'no' are two different strings.

Comment: @janusvm Yes, I tried that as well, it's still the same

Comment: @Vivia If you want useful answers, you're gonna have to post a more complete and reproducible example (i.e. one we can copy and paste to get the same error as you)

Comment: @janusvm I have added the sample of the data column in the question now.

Comment: @Vivia with the information given in your question, I am unable to reproduce your error. Given that `colval` is a string column of 'Y' and 'N', `sample['colval'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='N' else 1)` indeed converts them as wanted. It's hard to pin down why you can't, since your example code is very incomplete. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it difficult to repeat given the older version of Python and no access to the original data but your output above suggests whitespace in with the value. Try

```
sample['colval'] = sample['colval'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x.strip()=='N' else 1)
```